# Ray Tune | Conditional Search space in population based training

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, ray

I want to find the best number of hidden layers of this model

```
x1 = Input((window_size, 3), name='x1')
x2 = Input((window_size, 3), name='x2')
convA1 = Conv1D(config["Conv1DA"],11,padding='same',activation='relu')(x1)
for i in range(config["Conv1DAn"]):
    if i > 0: 
        convA2 = Conv1D(config[f'Conv1DAn_{i}'],11,padding='same',activation='relu')(convA1)
poolA = MaxPooling1D(3)(convA1)

convB1 = Conv1D(config["Conv1DB"],11,padding='same',activation='relu')(x2)
for i in range(config["Conv1DBn"]):
    if i > 0:
        convB2 = Conv1D(config[f'Conv1DBn_{i}'],11,padding='same',activation='relu')(convB1)
poolB = MaxPooling1D(3)(convB1)
AB = concatenate([poolA, poolB])

lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(config["LSTM1"], return_sequences=True))(AB)
drop1 = Dropout(config['dropout'])(lstm1)
for i in range(config['LSTMn']):
    if i > 0:
        lstm2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(config[f'LSTMn_{i}'], return_sequences=True))(drop1)
        drop1 =  Dropout(config['dropout'])(lstm2)   
lstm2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(config['LSTMn_l']))(drop1)
drop2 =  Dropout(config['dropout'])(lstm2)
y1_pred = Dense(4,kernel_regularizer='l2')(drop2)
model = Model(inputs =[x1, x2], outputs = [y1_pred])
```

Based on the high number of hyperparameters I found that PBT would be the best and fastest choice.
So I used ray tune the find the optimum value and by using this code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pbt = PopulationBasedTraining(
        perturbation_interval=600,
        hyperparam_mutations={
            "dropout": tune.uniform(0.1,0.5),
            "lr": tune.uniform(1e-5,1e-3),
            "Conv1DA": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DAn": tune.choice([0,1,2,3]),
            "Conv1DAn_1": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DAn_2": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DAn_3": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DB": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DBn": tune.choice([0,1,2,3]),
            "Conv1DBn_1": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DBn_2": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DBn_3": tune.randint(10,50),
            "LSTM1": tune.randint(10,50),
            "LSTMn": tune.choice([0,1,2,3]),
            "LSTMn_1": tune.randint(10,50),
            "LSTMn_2": tune.randint(10,50),
            "LSTMn_3": tune.randint(10,50),
            "LSTMn_l": tune.randint(10,50)})
    tuner = tune.Tuner(
        BroadModel,
        run_config=air.RunConfig(
            name="BroadPBT"+timestr,
            stop={"training_iteration": 4}),
        tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(
            reuse_actors=True,
            scheduler=pbt,
            metric="loss",
            mode="min",
            num_samples=2),
        param_space={
            "finish_fast": False,
            "batch_size": 1000,
            "epochs": 4       ,
            "dropout": tune.uniform(0.1,0.5),
            "lr": tune.uniform(1e-5,1e-3),
            "Conv1DA": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DAn": tune.choice([0,1,2,3]),
            "Conv1DAn_1": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DAn_2": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DAn_3": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DB": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DBn": tune.choice([0,1,2,3]),
            "Conv1DBn_1": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DBn_2": tune.randint(10,50),
            "Conv1DBn_3": tune.randint(10,50),
            "LSTM1": tune.randint(10,50),
            "LSTMn": tune.choice([0,1,2,3]),
            "LSTMn_1": tune.randint(10,50),
            "LSTMn_2": tune.randint(10,50),
            "LSTMn_3": tune.randint(10,50),
            "LSTMn_l": tune.randint(10,50)})
```

As you can see, the number of hidden layers (Conv1DAn, Conv1DBn, and LSTMn) is one of the parameter spaces. Could I change the code in a way that ignores the none used layers (conditional search space)?

Like this:

```
If Conv1DAn == 0:
  do not use Conv1DAn_1 ~ Conv1DAn_4
  if i > 0:
    for j in range(1,i):
      use Conv1DAn_j
```